# Creating bootstrap buttons dynamically

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to create bootstrap button dynamically? I have a textfile that have a list of items where I will make use of javascript to create an array with. That is where I would like to create bootstrap buttons dynamically with those items being the text within each button. If there is 10 items in the textfile, there would be 10 buttons created. Can someone tell me how can it be done or point me to some tutorial about it.

EDIT(Creation is possible now but not code for checking if buttons is created):

createButtons():

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url : 'http://localhost:8080/SSAD/type.txt',
    dataType : "text",
    success : function (filecontent) {
      var lines=filecontent.split('\n');
      $.each(lines, function() {
        if (this!='') {
            var word = this;
            word = word.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:_| |\b)(\w)/g, function(str, p1) { return p1.toUpperCase();});
            if ($('button:contains("'+word+'")').length==0) {
                var button='<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-inverse active" data-toggle="button tooltip" title="Click this to enable/disable viewing of'+this+'" onclick="toggleVisibility('+"'"+this+"'"+')">'+word+'</button>';
                $(".crisisButtons").append(button);
            }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-inverse" onclick="createButtons">Click me!</button>

<div class="crisisButtons"></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes. It is very easy.

textfile.txt

```
button1
button2
button3
button4
button5
button6
button7
button8
button9
button10
```

code

```
<div id="textfile-buttons"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url : 'textfile.txt',
    dataType : "text",
    success : function (filecontent) {
      var lines=filecontent.split('\n');
      $.each(lines, function() {
        if (this!='') {
          var button='<button class="btn btn-primary">'+this+'</button>&nbsp;';
          $("#textfile-buttons").append(button);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Result
[image]

Of course you need to assign a `click`-handler to the buttons, or a link if you use `<a>` -tags instead of `<button>`.

---

**Update**

If you want to check if a `button` with a certain text already exists, modify the `$.each` loop

```
$.each(lines, function() {
  if (this!='') {
    //check if a button with "this" text not already exists
    if ($('button:contains("'+this+'")').length==0) {
      var button='<button class="btn btn-primary">'+this+'</button>&nbsp;';
      $("#textfile-buttons").append(button);
    }
  }
});
```

So, even if textfile.txt contains 
button1
button2
button3
button3
button3
button3
button7
button8
button9
button10

only one button3 will be created.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is it possible to check if a button have been previously created so that it will not create it again. Example: buttons are created by clicking a button. So if button 2 was created before and if I click on the button to create buttons, it should not create button 2 again.

Comment: **What** is not working? You must be specific. Sure you have copy-pasted correctly?

Comment: I created a button to create buttons base on the items in the textfile. It will create the same list of buttons again. I tried addingmultiple similar entry into the textfile too and it creates them too. The only difference is my var button have a button type.

Comment: It is impossible to guess. Show your code (edit the question)